# Running Sum output wrong order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I need a running sum of my tables, where I have written my code, but cannot get it to work.

This is what I get

[image]

This is what I need

[image]

This is my code

```
SELECT 
id,
date
saldo,
cast(sum(saldo) over (order by date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as float) as running_Total

FROM orders

order by date desc;
```

I simply cannot get my head around what is wrong. I have searched the internet for hours. I also have problems moving the decimals and commas to be in the right places.

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? (2) What is the datatyope of column `saldo`?

Comment: I tested my code on some other data and it worked. There is some sort of problem with the data I need to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nothing but ordering by date descendingly for the SELECT statement such as

```
SELECT id, date, saldo,
       SUM(saldo) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS running_Total
FROM orders
ORDER BY date DESC
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c461e6b8801694227329cba767b898ab)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I need to add my orders in desc.

Comment: Can I ask you a followup question? I tried the code on some other data and it worked as it should, also adding the date desc. However, It output the values as strings I think. How would the code look, if I need the output value to be formated as a number ? Thank you!

Comment: what's your DBMS, and can you share your effort within a demo like the link within the answer? Btw, is the data type of `date` column string(or string alike such as varchar,varchar2) @Kasper ?

Comment: Ofcourse! I changed my code and added my changes for the formatting. I am using mysql and date is formated as date. Basically, I need the same formatting as in Saldo. Should I specify how the decimal should be ?

Comment: I found the solution! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have actually have multiple `id`s in your data and that what you need is a `partition by`:

```
SELECT id, date saldo,
       sum(saldo) over (partition by id order by date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as running_Total
FROM orders
ORDER BY id, date;
```

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea too. Thank you for your answer!